# Does Lubuntu 11.10 have a indicator?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, touchpad, lubuntu

Will Touchpad-indicator work when enabled on Lubuntu 11.10's Indicator?

Comment: no answer for this?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Touchpad-indicator appears to work on Lubuntu 11.10 (tested on an eeepc 1005ha). It is not in the official repositories but if you are comfortable with installing applications from a PPA it is available.

To install touchpad-indicator, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

To set it up:

Menu --> Accessories --> Touchpad-Indicator

This should insert a touchpad icon in the taskbar. Click on this icon and choose 'Preferences' to set the options (including autostart).

NOTE: If you have problems adding the repository, check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, touchpad-indicator works on LXDE and therefore also Lubuntu.